# How to set points of UIbutton like same shape like cashapelayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, calayer

I'm drawing chart and i want to add buttons on calayers.This red and blue color shapes are CAShaperlayer. i have used uibezier path to draw those layers.

[image]

Comment: check this: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the good library to solve your problem.

[image]

[You can download the source code from here.](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton)

[Check into appetize.io](https://appetize.io/embed/17bq7gz7e9t18u8exjxgr3fbuw?device=iphone5s&scale=75&autoplay=false&orientation=portrait&deviceColor=black&xdocMsg=true)